# MongoDB stepDown fails in a PSA Architecture

Tags: replication, mongodb, high-availability

I have set up a MongoDB cluster using a 3-Member Primary-Secondary-Arbiter Architecture

## Environment:

- LXC containers
- Linux Debian Stretch (9.8)
- MongoDB server version: 4.0.6

## MongoDB Containers:

- lxc-mongodb-01 (primary)
- lxc-mongodb-02 (secondary)
- lxc-mongodb-03 (arbitrer)

## Replication Status

Everything seems to work fine and replication is working:

```
np:PRIMARY> rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
source: lxc-mongodb-02:27017
    syncedTo: Wed Mar 06 2019 12:08:27 GMT+0100 (CET)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

## Switchover fails

But when I try to switchover primary/secondary using rs.stepDown() it fails with a "No electable secondaries caught up" error message:

```
np:PRIMARY> rs.stepDown(60, 30)
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1551870647, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "No electable secondaries caught up as of 2019-03-06T12:11:19.140+0100Please use the replSetStepDown command with the argument {force: true} to force node to step down.",
    "code" : 262,
    "codeName" : "ExceededTimeLimit",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1551870647, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"+/jQR8cG+y/bPtoF7gnv2Pmn2BY="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6653042051040411649")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is a non-production cluster, so there is no transaction in progress.

#### Logs from server01 (primary) :

```
2019-03-06T12:08:07.709+0100 I ACCESS   [conn17] Successfully authenticated as principal root on admin
2019-03-06T12:10:49.140+0100 I COMMAND  [conn17] Attempting to step down in response to replSetStepDown command
2019-03-06T12:11:19.140+0100 I COMMAND  [conn17] command admin.$cmd appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: replSetStepDown { replSetStepDown: 60.0, secondaryCatchUpPeriodSecs: 30.0, lsid: { id: UUID("8941645a-c582-4353-b216-6e5ee91c08b0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1551870507, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 484DDC04A03F9CBEDA0E5FA5E4F438F414E43E8F), keyId: 6653042051040411649 } }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 ok:0 errMsg:"No electable secondaries caught up as of 2019-03-06T12:11:19.140+0100Please use the replSetStepDown command with the argument {force: true} to force node to step down." errName:ExceededTimeLimit errCode:262 reslen:385 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, W: 2 } } } protocol:op_msg 29999ms
```

#### Logs from server02 (secondary) :

```
2019-03-06T12:10:52.278+0100 I REPL     [replication-1] Restarting oplog query due to error: InterruptedDueToReplStateChange: error in fetcher batch callback :: caused by :: operation was interrupted. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp(1551870647, 1), t: 8 }[-3124663669138993987]. Restarts remaining: 1
2019-03-06T12:10:52.278+0100 I REPL     [replication-1] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: lxc-mongodb-01:27017 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp(1551870647, 1) } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 2000, batchSize: 13981010, term: 8, readConcern: { afterClusterTime: Timestamp(1551870647, 1) } } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $oplogQueryData: 1, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" } } active: 1 findNetworkTimeout: 7000ms getMoreNetworkTimeout: 10000ms shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 6603 -- target:lxc-mongodb-01:27017 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp(1551870647, 1) } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 2000, batchSize: 13981010, term: 8, readConcern: { afterClusterTime: Timestamp(1551870647, 1) } } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
2019-03-06T12:10:52.279+0100 W REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Fetcher stopped querying remote oplog with error: InvalidSyncSource: Sync source cannot be behind me, and if I am up-to-date with the sync source, it must have a higher lastOpCommitted. My last fetched oplog optime: { ts: Timestamp(1551870647, 1), t: 8 }, latest oplog optime of sync source: { ts: Timestamp(1551870647, 1), t: 8 }, my lastOpCommitted: { ts: Timestamp(1551870647, 1), t: 8 }, lastOpCommitted of sync source: { ts: Timestamp(1551870647, 1), t: 8 }
2019-03-06T12:10:52.279+0100 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Clearing sync source lxc-mongodb-01:27017 to choose a new one.
2019-03-06T12:10:52.279+0100 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] could not find member to sync from
2019-03-06T12:10:57.276+0100 I REPL     [SyncSourceFeedback] SyncSourceFeedback error sending update to lxc-mongodb-01:27017: InvalidSyncSource: Sync source was cleared. Was lxc-mongodb-01:27017
2019-03-06T12:11:27.284+0100 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] sync source candidate: lxc-mongodb-01:27017
2019-03-06T12:11:27.286+0100 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Changed sync source from empty to lxc-mongodb-01:27017
2019-03-06T12:11:28.833+0100 I NETWORK  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Starting new replica set monitor for np/lxc-mongodb-01:27017,lxc-mongodb-02:27017
```

#### Logs from server03 (arbitrer) :

```
2019-03-06T12:11:29.428+0100 I NETWORK  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Starting new replica set monitor for np/lxc-mongodb-01:27017,lxc-mongodb-02:27017
2019-03-06T12:11:29.429+0100 I NETWORK  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Starting new replica set monitor for np/lxc-mongodb-01:27017,lxc-mongodb-02:27017
```

Looking at the documentation and some threads, I tried tuned a few settings, with no success:

```
replication.enableMajorityReadConcern = false
writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault = false
```

## Question

So, what am I missing to make stepDown work as expected?

## EDIT 07/03/2019

Here is `rs.status()` output from the primary:

```
np:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "np",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:17.623Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(8),
    "syncingTo" : "",
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        }
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "lxc-mongodb-01:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 75954,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:09Z"),
            "syncingTo" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1551870155, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2019-03-06T11:02:35Z"),
            "configVersion" : 4,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "lxc-mongodb-03:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 75952,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:16.005Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:17.410Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncingTo" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "lxc-mongodb-02:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 75952,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:09Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:09Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:16.008Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2019-03-07T08:08:15.798Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncingTo" : "lxc-mongodb-01:27017",
            "syncSourceHost" : "lxc-mongodb-01:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 0,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 4
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1551946089, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"ZPnNWVwjB1K9jdaSHlnfnmRPqqM="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6653042051040411649")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `rs.conf()` output from the primary:

```
np:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "np",
    "version" : 4,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : false,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "lxc-mongodb-01:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "lxc-mongodb-03:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : true,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "lxc-mongodb-02:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 0
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
        "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        },
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5c545a7d4e358716c8129ac6")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is *No electable secondaries* because priority of secondary node is set to 0 (see `rs.conf()` in the original post. Thanks to [Mani](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/172114/mani) for his suggestion!).

I updated **priority** (and **votes**) for lxc-mongodb-02 (_id = 2):

```
cfg = rs.conf();
cfg.members[0].priority = 2;
cfg.members[2].votes = 1;
cfg.members[2].priority = 1;
rs.reconfig(cfg);
```

lxc-mongodb-02 is now electable as a PRIMARY.

That being said, I just realized that a permanent switchover will be performed by changing the priority rather than using `rs.stepDown()` command.

So to promote lxc-mongodb-02 as the primary, I run:

```
cfg = rs.conf();
cfg.members[2].priority = 3;
np:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig(cfg);
{
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1551953687, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1551953687, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"r4jVzPM1nUnJ44THZ3E+cJA1SDU="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6653042051040411649")
        }
    }
}
```